# Retrieve SharePoint list in DataTable with Condition

Tags: sharepoint, datatable, caml, sharepoint-list

** I have a Sharepoint List called "Resources" and have various Fields as shown below and same returns as DataTable:

```
ID    Title     Role       LoginName    Enable[Yes/No] 
1    Pranav    Developer    BW\PPB       Yes
2    Rohit     Tester       BW\RW        No
3    Sarang    Account      BW\SJ        No
4    Amit      Soft.Eng     BW\AI        Yes
4    Kunal     Soft.Eng     BW\KT        Yes
```

**My code:

```
public static DataTable GetListData()
        {
            DataTable returnTable = null;

            SPSite thisSite = null;
            SPWeb thisWeb = null;
            SPList thisList = null;

             try
               {
            thisSite = new SPSite(siteLink);
            thisWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb();
            thisList = thisWeb.Lists["Resources"];
            if (thisList.Items.Count > 0)
              {
            filterQuery = new SPQuery();
            filterQuery.ViewFields = PopulateFieldsParameter("Title,Role,AddtionalRoles,Designation,LoginName,ClientBillable,NonBillable, EnableChatting,LoggedIn,EnableTimesheet,DesignationTitle,pmPODEnable");
            returnTable = thisList.GetItems(filterQuery).GetDataTable();
               }
        returnTable = thisList.Items.GetDataTable();
        }
         return returnTable;
         }
```

With this above code i am able to retrieve whole list data but i want to get table(rows) whose Enable is Yes.

**Actual Output**

```
    ID    Title     Role       LoginName    Enable[Yes/No] 
    1    Pranav    Developer    BW\PPB       Yes
    2    Rohit     Tester       BW\RW        No
    3    Sarang    Account      BW\SJ        No
    4    Amit      Soft.Eng     BW\AI        Yes
    5    Kunal     Soft.Eng     BW\KT        Yes
```

**Expected Output** -Condition= Enable == Yes

```
ID    Title     Role       LoginName    Enable[Yes/No] 

1    Pranav    Developer    BW\PPB       Yes
4    Amit      Soft.Eng     BW\AI        Yes
5    Kunal     Soft.Eng     BW\KT        Yes
```

Help..!!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Query property from SPQuery
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457534%28v=office.15%29.aspx